# Kafka Connect InsertField transform with dynamic values

Tags: apache-kafka, transform, apache-kafka-connect, upsert

I've run into a situation where I need to insert a new field to a Kafka Connect record, but it seems like the InsertField transform is limited to static values.

https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/transforms/insertfield.html

Is there a way to add a dynamic value based off of other fields in the record?

The reason I need this is because I'm using JDBC Source and Sink Connectors to transfer data between two databases. On the sink side, I'm doing upserts. Because of that I need the following fields:

```
        "insert.mode": "upsert",
        "pk.mode": "record_value",
        "pk.fields": "TABLE_ID",
```

This works fine, but it ties me into having one connector file per table because in my source database all of the tables have primary keys in the form tableName_ID. So pk.fields is always going to be different.

I was thinking in my sink database I could add a new field that my application wouldn't know about, but Kafka Connect would use for the purposes of upsert primary keys. It would be called something like `kafka_id` and would be the same for every table. I'd like to add this field in my source config and then just update pk.fields in my sink. Is there any way I can do this? Do I need to write a custom transform? Thanks!

Comment: Maybe this transformation https://jcustenborder.github.io/kafka-connect-documentation/projects/kafka-connect-transform-common/transformations/PatternRename.html could be useful

Comment: Good suggestion, and I was actually looking at that one. Unfortunately for me, field.pattern would have to be based off the topic/table name which I don't think I have access to from within there? I don't think I could do something like field.pattern: "^${topic}".

Comment: I think you can use pattern `.*_id`. Another option is your own SMT: ConnectRecord has info about its topic (https://kafka.apache.org/23/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/connect/connector/ConnectRecord.html#topic--).

Comment: Ah, ok I see what you're saying now. That's another good thought, but unfortunately there could (and almost definitely will) be other fields in my row that match the same pattern SOMETHING_ID. Foreign keys mostly. So doing that would end up with multiple fields with the same name in the json "transforms.patternRename.field.pattern" : "^.*_ID", "transforms.patternRename.field.replacement" : "id". I think my best bet is probably my own SMT. Thanks for the link

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case the best option is your own Kafka Connect SMT: You can use topic info from [ConnectRecord](https://kafka.apache.org/25/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/connect/connector/ConnectRecord.html).

[Example](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-insert-uuid) of SMT from [`How to Use Single Message Transforms in Kafka Connect`](https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-connect-single-message-transformation-tutorial-with-examples/) article.